# HTTP "Bad Request" error calling DataSnap service over 3G

Tags: delphi, http, 3g, datasnap, bad-request

I've just discovered an error my DataSnap client is receiving calling a server method when passing a particularly large string as the parameter to the method. The call causes a DBXException error with "Bad Request". My client is running on an Android phone and the error only occurs when using 3G, on Wi-fi everything works fine. Every other call works fine, it's just this call with the large parameter.

Is there some restriction on the size of the underlying HTTP call when using 3G networks? My DataSnap server is built with Delphi XE2, I'm using the DataSnap mobile connector framework for Android (Java).

Update : the mobile I was testing it on is on the 3 network (Three).  I've since tried it on another phone which is on O2 and this worked fine on 3G.  Could the problem be mobile network specific?

Any help appreciated,

Jonathan

Comment: Maybe DataSnap allows to log the request, or to use a proxy so the HTTP request can be captured?

Comment: Ah didn't think of using a proxy server, that may well help see what is being sent, will give it a go.